# Git rebase against a release branch for things like hotfixes and patches

Tags: git, version-control, rebase

At work we use a `develop` branch for day-to-day work - new features, bug fixes, et al. When we are ready to release, we merge the devleop branch into master, tag, and release.

If we are needing to do a hotfix which needs to be released immediately, we create a branch off `master`, apply changes, and merge accordingly (including merging `master` back into `develop`). There are no issues with what I have described so far.

I was just recently working on a small bug fix that was to be included in the next release. So created my usual branch off of `develop`, made a few commits, and submitted a PR. Then a manager wanted the fix in today as a hotfix. OK - simple, I'll just rebase my work against `master` and open the PR against master. However, running `git rebase master` did not replay my work against the current HEAD commit on master. Instead, git told me that everything was "up to date". I then opened the PR against master, and my PR contained **all new work** from the `develop` branch, not just my bug fix.

I was able to do an interactive rebase and drop all of the commits which shouldn't have been there, but this seems kind of tedious and error prone. Is there a more sane way of achieving this goal of *rebasing against an older yet up-to-date branch*?

Comment: How many commits on your little branch?   If just a few I might try "git checkout hotfix; git cherry-pick develop..my-branch".

Comment: Fortunately it was only a few commits I had to drop as we released earlier in the week, but the point of this question is to not _need_ to know how many commits or history or anything. I want my work based against another branch, whether it's 1 commit or 100.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of rebasing "against `master`" (i.e. "with `master` as the upstream" per the command you used), you needed to rebase your work `--onto master` with the upstream set to `develop`.

```
git rebase --onto master develop my_fix
```

Bear in mind this creates a new and untested code state; since hot-fixes are fast-tracked to production a special eye to testing it is warranted.

Comment: Awesome - I have never even heard of `--onto`. That was exactly what I was looking for.